# CS cart:How to override currencies.tpl file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, content-management-system, cs-cart

I am using CS cart version 4.4.3.

I want to change the template structure as well as design of currencies.tpl file. How can I do that, so that in future updates  override file will not change?

Currently file is located at:-

`design\themes\responsive\templates\blocks`

I have tried to override it via pasting tpl file on my_changes addon:-

```
design\themes\bharat_theme\templates\addons\my_changes\blocks\currencies.tpl
```

But it is not working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try

```
design\themes\bharat_theme\templates\addons\my_changes\overrides\blocks\currencies.tpl
```

please clear cache after

```
./admin.php?cc&ctpl
```

Comment: Thanks. It works like charm . Do you know any tutorial that help to convert cs cart template from scratch. I mean to say from HTML to Cs cart. I checked youtube tutorials. But they are just providing knowledge of basics